# Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I teach a class where we are working with Hibernate to generate the Java classes associated with our MySQL DB. Some of my students are having this issue when creating the reverse engineering file:

> Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database.
> Probably a JDBC driver problem.

When we create the configuration file, Eclipse is able to ping with the DB, so I don't think the issue has to do with the versions. We are using the latest connector (8.0.22) and the latest version of Hibernate (5.4) while our MySQL version is 8.0.19. We have tried to downgrade the connector but the error still persists.

[image]

Is there any way of checking a detailed log with the error? This error is vague enough that I don't know where to check any more information, I still don't know if it has to do with versions, or it can be a JDBC issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and don't post screenshots of things that can be posted as code-formatted text.

Comment: Also, the `MySQLInnoDBDialect` has been deprecated, please try a more recent dialect (e.g. `MySQL8Dialect`), it might solve your problem.

Comment: Your error message should come with a stacktrace. The "Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database" exception is probably just a wrapper for the actual exception that causes the problem. Do you have a complete stacktrace from your students?